# Is local secret store best practice for sensitive data?

Tags: azure, design-patterns, azure-webapps, azure-app-configuration

I am using Azure App Configuration on a team project and am wondering what would be the best way to store the connection string, so that it is protected, yet not every developer would have to install it to his local secret store?

For production I am thinking of storing it in an env variable which the application will be getting (it's an Azure Web App).

What would be the best practice to store the conn string for development and is storing it in an env var in prod good practice?

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to use Azure Key Vault and store the connection string on it. Then, add a Managed Identity to your web app and create a policy, so only your web app will be able to retrieve the connection string.

Also, you can grant in your SQL Database the permission to the managed identity to connect on it (rather than Username and Password). Even if the connection string got leaked, hackers won't be able to impersonate your web app.

EDIT: Adding more links

[how to use managed identities to connect to sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-managed-identities-sql)

[access policy to enable managed identities to connect to Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/key-vault-secrets)

Comment: That's great and all, but how do I access the Key Vault while debugging locally?

Comment: different key vaults for different environments

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio is correct, as long as the key name is the same the only difference will be the URL for the dev keyvault vs the prod keyvault.  We have a KeyVault learning path here that goes over this scenario. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/manage-secrets-with-azure-key-vault/

Comment: Yeah, **that's great** where do I store the prod KeyVault connection string, then? And if you say I should store it in a different app configuration and access that through another KeyVault I'd say you've missed the point.

Comment: @mummy you are missing the point here. Using a managed identify removes the need to use a connection string. So you do not need to store it. For local development see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-to-service-authentication#local-development-authentication